# ZF2 Google Maps Module - Zend\ServiceManager\ServiceManager::get was unable to fetch or create an instance for GMaps\Service\GoogleMap

Tags: php, module, zend-framework2

I'm trying to use this module, https://github.com/gowsram/zf2-google-maps- , but I'm running into a problem.

```
Zend\ServiceManager\ServiceManager::get was unable to fetch or create an instance for GMaps\Service\GoogleMap
```

I have followed the instruction in the github readme, and have cloned the project into my vendors directory.

From what I understand, the line which calls the ServiceLocator,

```
$map = $this->getServiceLocator()->get('GMaps\Service\GoogleMap');
```

isn't pointing to the right place. Unfortunately my knowledge of how the service locator works isn't deep enough to figure out how to fix the problem, despite attempts to remedy this by diving into the docs. It's all a little over my head.

Thanks for any input you may be able to provide!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have you edited your `application.config.php` file so that the `modules` array contains `GMaps`?  From the look of the error, the module isn't running since the service is not registered with the ServiceManager.

That step appeared to be skipped over in the installation instructions but you should add it to your application config so it runs the module's `Module.php` code.

***application.config.php***

```
return array(
    'modules' => array(
        'Application',
        'GMaps',
    ),
    /...
);
```

Comment: This fixed my problem, thanks! But I think there are deeper problems with the module beyond what I encountered since it's can't even be initialized.